# Nuxt3 Middleware - Access VueX stores

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, middleware, nuxt3

I'm migrating a Nuxt2 app to Nuxt3. In a middleware i access a store state using 'context' like:

```js
export default function (context) {
   const userName = context.store.state.common.auth.user
}
```

In Nuxt3 using **defineNuxtRouteMiddleware** to create the middleware , how do i access the stores i have in the application ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
import { defineNuxtRouteMiddleware } from 'nuxt3'

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((context) => {
  // Import the store module you want to access
  import('yourStorePathHere').then((module) => {
    // Now you can access the store's state
    const user = module.default.state.user
  })
})
```

Comment: if 'yourStorePathHere' equals 'context.store.state.common.auth', or the file path, i doesn't work.